# How can i add checkbox in my webgrid in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add checkbox in my webgrid so anybody can tell me how can I do this? And also tell me how can I select all checkbox and delete them. This is my code:-

```
@{
  var grid = new WebGrid(
    Model, rowsPerPage: 5,
    defaultSort: "CatagoryId",
    columnNames: new[] { "Category_Name", "Parent_Category_ID", "Category_Desc", "IsGenderApplicable", "IsAgeApplicable", "IsActive" }
  );    
}
@grid.GetHtml(
  fillEmptyRows: false,
  mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,

  columns:grid.Columns(
    grid.Column("Category_Name", header: "Catagory Name"),
    grid.Column("Parent_Category_ID", header: "Parant CatID"),
    grid.Column("Category_Desc", header: "Description"),
    grid.Column("IsGenderApplicable", header: "Gender Application"),
    grid.Column("IsAgeApplicable", header:"Age Application"),
    grid.Column("IsActive", header: "Active")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a checkbox as:

```
   grid.Column(format: @<text><input name="chkbox" 
          type="checkbox" value="some value" /></text>),
```

Your second query:  how can I select all checkbox ?

Please refer to this blog: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/273164/mvc-checkbox-checked-rows-in-the-web-grid